# Tkinter file dialogue limitation

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a file dialogue for a project using tkinter,I tried askopenfilenames() and askopenfoldernames() function. I couldn't find a function to open multiple items together; including folders and files. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What code did you use? What error did you get if any? Please read [How to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That said `askopenfilenames()` is the correct method to open multiple files. It Return () or the tuple of the absolute paths of the chosen files. Then it is up to you to use that tuple to open the files.

Comment: askopenfilenames(): open a dialogue where you can select multiple files by pressing ctrl button.askopenfoldernames():select multiple folder by pressing ctrl key. The problem is,I cannot select folder and file together. Is there any way to do so??